# Switching from http to https in my sitemap will affect my SEO?

Tags: https, sitemap

my site has over 5 million pages. Before changing all links from http to https, I had around 14.000 visits per day form google results, after that, the site is receiving barely 600 visits per day.

Should I switch back all links in the sitemap to http, or should I wait a little longer for them to be re-crawled?

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Where does this graph come from?   If it is from Search Console, you probably just need to verify your HTTPS site there.

Comment: Switching from HTTP to HTTPS is a major disruption that we seem the be getting several questions on a week. It is just part of the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're pulling that graph from Google Search Console, you should have all version of your site added. In order to view the metrics for the https version that's the property you'd view the data in going forward:

> If your site supports multiple protocols (http:// and https://), you
>   must add each as a separate site.
>   https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en